# Can kCNF have less than k variables per clause?

Tags: computer-science, propositional-calculus

An example given by my prof in her notes:

> The following formula is in 4CNF: $(w\vee y\vee \neg z)\wedge(w\vee\neg x\vee z)\wedge(w\vee\neg x\vee \neg y\vee z)$

I originally thought that maybe the example was a typo, but given a definition she gave before that, saying that "A formula is in kCNF if it has a maximal of k variables per disjunction". Is this technically 4CNF if it has two clauses that don't have 4 variables in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to your title question.  A statement in kCNF form can have fewer than $k$ variables in a clause. Put differently, a statement in kCNF form has AT MOST (maximum of) $k$ variables per clause/conjunct.

The fact that *one* of the conjuncts (clause) in your example has $4$ variables (the third/last clause) means it qualifies as 4CNF statement. It doesn't matter that two of the clauses do not have 4 variables in it.

Comment: So does it follow then that CNF is the same as kCNF?

Comment: It could, depending on k. Your example wouldn't qualify as a 3CNF, but it is both a CNF and a 4CNF statement.

Comment: Yes I am, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!